# ORACLE TIMESTAMP FORMAT MASK

Tags: sql, oracle

maybe someone can help me with:
I have date as input in that format

```
'2014-06-26T14:36:37.000+0000'
```

And i want to insert this date in column **TIMECOL** with **TIMESTAMP(3) WITH TIME ZONE** type,
so i do this:

```
 INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(ID,NAME,TIMECOL) VALUES (NULL, 'TESTN',TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-06-26T14:36:37.000+0000', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3+TMZ'));
```

But i got error:
**ORA-01821: date format not recognized**.

What mask i need to use?

Comment: The order is wrong in TO_TIMESTAMP. Must be TO_TIMESTAMP(value, format). But it does not solve the problem alone.

Comment: sorry, my fault, i edit my code in question, problem still take a place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to use `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` in order to get a timestamp with timezone. The following works:

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2014-06-26T14:36:37.000+0000', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3 TZD') from dual
```

So, your `INSERT` may be,

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(ID,NAME,TIMECOL)
VALUES (NULL,
        'TESTN',
        TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2014-06-26T14:36:37.000+0000', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3 TZD'));
```

Comment: thx, you are right. but can you tell me why after insert in my column i have timestamp in that format '26-JUN-14 02.36.37.000000000 PM +03:00'
especially why timezone +03:00, and not 000, i guess its depends from oracle db settings.

Comment: Not sure, but I think, It directly sets the current timezone of Oracle. You can check it by SELECT SESSIONTIMEZONE FROM DUAL.

Comment: Do you know why on earth Oracle has chosen to provide a separate TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ instead of just having TO_TIMESTAMP supporting it? I mean - we dont expect to have a TO_NUMBER_WITH_DECIMALS in addition to a TO_NUMBER handling only integers.

Comment: @JensKrogsboell - probably because it has a different return type; `TO_TIMESTAMP` returns `TIMESTAMP`, while `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` returns `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. If the former accepted the time zone info then it would have to do some kind of adjustment which would be messy and (more) confusing, and you'd likely end up with the wrong value in the OP's column. Don't think the comparison with `TO_NUMBER` really works as that does always return a `NUMBER`, even if that is then assigned to an `INTEGER` variable.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble with this Oracle #$%%^ is that the formatting on the TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ and FROM_TZ is horrible. If you want to insert the value into a date field in a format you can actually use, try the below. You won't find this on the Oracle Support Forum.

-- The real format

```
SELECT to_date(to_char(from_tz(CAST (sysdate AS TIMESTAMP), 'US/Eastern') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS'), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS') as MyDateToInsert from dual;
```